# How to display the json object output in the ui?

Tags: java, jquery, json, servlets

I have the following code in my servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String line;
    StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
    String starttime = "2010-01-16T12:07:48";
    String endtime = "2010-02-16T12:18:13";

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9200/indexname/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source&pretty=1&size=10000000");

        String payload = "{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"filter\":{\"range\":{\"Date\":{\"lte\":\""+endtime+"\",\"gte\":\""+starttime+"\"}}}}},\"_source\":{\"include\":[\"ID\",\"Name\",\"Status\",\"Date\"]}}";

        HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection1.setDoInput(true);
        connection1.setDoOutput(true);
        connection1.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection1.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStreamWriter writer1 = new OutputStreamWriter(connection1.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        writer1.write(payload1);
        writer1.close();

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection1.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
             jsonString1.append(line);
        }

        br1.close();
        connection1.disconnect();               

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(jsonString);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

I want to pass the jsonstring1 as a json object or arraylist to the UI and display it in the UI in an alert box? Please advice on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

u can convert this json object and get every property in variable and use it by using lib like simple-json

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

and u can use code like this for convert your json object

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString1);
String filteredSt= jsonObject.get("filtered");
```

u can search in what u need take a look in this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)